# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(x_n-\ln(n+1)\big)$ for $x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{-x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I was just going through some of the problems from an intro analysis course I took in the fall $2010$ and was hoping people could shed some light on some problems I feel that I never fully solved. Here's a problem in question:

Let $x_{0}$ be a real number, and define a sequence $\left(\,{x_{n}}\,\right)_{n\ \geq\ 0}\ $ recursively by setting
$$
x_{n + 1} = x_{n} + {\rm e}^{-x_{n}}\,,
$$
for all $n \geq 0$. Evaluate ( with proof )
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\left[x_{n} - \ln\left(\,{n + 1}\,\right)\right].
$$

We solved several problems involving such recursively defined limits, and almost always employed
$\mbox{Ces}{\rm \grave{a}}\mbox{ro}$ means, and I always struggled with them. If someone could sketch a proof ( or give steps for me to fill in ) I would be more than grateful. I've googled a little bit looking for similar examples to get more practice, but haven't had much luck so if anyone knows any other similar problems ([this](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/sequence/hardlim/hardlim.html) is about the only thing I've found), I'd be happy to hear them as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you managed to prove that $x_n$ is increasing and $x_n \to \infty$.

Denote $y_n=e^{x_n-\ln(n+1)}=\displaystyle\frac{e^{x_n}}{n+1}$.

Now we attempt to use [Stolz-Cesàro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):

$$\frac{e^{x_{n+1}}-e^{x_n}}{n+2-(n+1)}=e^{x_n}(e^{x_{n+1}-x_n}-1)=\frac{e^{e^{-x_n}}-1}{e^{-x_n}}\to 1$$

since $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y}=1$ and $e^{-x_n}\to 0$.

By Stolz-Cesàro, $y_n \to 1$ and this means that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n-\ln(n+1)= 0$.