# Prove that sequence $b_n=a_n-\ln n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ is positive and decreasing if $a_0=1, a_{n+1}=a_n+e^{-a_n}, n\in\mathbb{N_0}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

You have the following recurrence formula:

$$a_0=1,\quad a_{n+1}=a_n+e^{-a_n}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N_0}$$

Now define sequence:

$$b_n=a_n-\ln n,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Prove that:

$$0 \lt b_{n+1} \lt b_n, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}\tag{1}$$

...and determine:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$$

My try:

Firstly, let us make some observations about $a_n$. It obviously holds that:

$$a_{n + 1} > a_{n} > 1, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Now, suppose $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a limit $a \in \mathbb{R}$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Then, we would have:

$$a = a + e^{-a}$$

which has no solution for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So we conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = +\infty$. Also, we can write $b_n$ in the following way:

$$b_{n + 1} = b_{n} + e^{-a_n} - \ ln{\frac{n + 1}{n}}$$.

From this, and if $(1)$ holds it is quite trivial to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = 0$. Now, I have not managed to prove $(1)$ since every inequality I tried to use was not nearly strong enough. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If $a_0$ = $1$ , doesn't that violate your claim that $a_n$ > 1 for all n?

Comment: @OmarShaaban I have clearly stated that it holds for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ not $\mathbb{N_0}$

Comment: To avoid confusion, I think you should state what  $\mathbb{N}$ is since some consider 
it starting from $0$ and some consider it starting from $1$.

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180943/compute-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracx-n-ln-n